# How to make parameter in xpath and make codes easier to read if there are several same lines, java, selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, parameters

I wrote this boolean method but I want to make it shorter and smarter since there are 3 same lines with quite the same `XPath`.
Could anyone help me with this, please? thanks

```
    public boolean VerifyKORSecDispaly() {
    
    boolean a = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("(//tr[@data-testid='row']//td[@class='kor'])[1]//span[@class='da']"))
            .getText().contains("d");
    boolean b = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("(//tr[@data-testid='row']//td[@class='kor'])[2]//span[@class='da']"))
            .getText().contains("d");
    boolean c = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("(//tr[@data-testid='row']//td[@class='kor'])[3]//span[@class='da']"))
            .getText().contains("d");

    if (a == true && b == true && c == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `List<>` since you use indexes in xpath.

`//tr[@data-testid='row']//td[@class='kor']` <- this selector would return multiple elements

Based on these elements, we can find `span[@class='da']` element.

Code:

```
public boolean VerifyKORSecDispaly() {
    boolean a = doesRowTextContain(0, "d");
    boolean b = doesRowTextContain(1, "d");
    boolean c = doesRowTextContain(2, "d");

    if (a == true && b == true && c == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean doesRowTextContain(int index, String expectedString) {
    By spanSelector = By.xpath(".//span[@class='da']"); //the dot . reduces the scope of the element. Instead of searching through all the elements in source, we'll reduce the scope to parent element
    List<WebElement> dataRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@data-testid='row']//td[@class='kor']"));
    
    return dataRows.get(index).findElement(spanSelector).getText().contains(expectedString);
}
```

One more thing is - you don't have to compare `a, b or c` with `true` as it's default expected value in `if` statement.

```
    if (a && b && c) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Or even

`return a && b && c` :)

Final methods could look like this:

```
public boolean VerifyKORSecDispaly() {
    return doesRowTextContain(0, "d") && doesRowTextContain(1, "d") && doesRowTextContain(2, "d");
}

private boolean doesRowTextContain(int index, String expectedString) {
    By spanSelector = By.xpath(".//span[@class='da']"); //the dot . reduces the scope of the element. Instead of searching through all the elements in source, we'll reduce the scope to parent element
    List<WebElement> dataRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@data-testid='row']//td[@class='kor']"));
    
    return dataRows.get(index).findElement(spanSelector).getText().contains(expectedString);
}
```

Comment: Hi Fenio, Thank you very much for the reply! Very smart way thanks a lot.
But I tried this method "private WebElement doesRowTextContain(int index, String expectedString)" shows error as need to return as boolean, could you please help to check? thanks!

Comment: @Ashley Ah, yes, fixed